# What is the best way to add option to a dropdown list generated with plugin msDropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, msdropdown

I am using jQuery plugin msDropdown for displaying dopdown-lists with images.

I try to dynamically add an option and to refresh a msDropdown dropdown list , 
I tried

```
dropdown.add(json_row);
dropdown.refresh();
dropdown.set("selectedIndex", new_index);
dropdown.refresh();
```

I have issues :

- it takes several seconds  to add the row (really too much time)
- it doesn't display the icon , just displays text
- it doesn't set the new index

Do you know how to make it quickly and efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

> it takes several seconds to add the row (really too much time)

[I leave a site if you see something](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/examples/help.html)

> it doesn't display the icon , just displays text

In the json_row not set "image" parameter.

> it doesn't set the new index

oDropdown.on("change", setSelectedIndex);

//setSelectedIndex It is a function to execute dropdown.set("selectedIndex", new_index);